# типы данных в глобальных массивах

Tags: php

Правильно ли я понимаю, что делаю пост запрос с нужными мне параметрами, они всегда будут приходить мне в строках?
Например, я не могу постом отправить key с булевским значением true или false, мне придёт строка true

Comment: да, правильно понимаете.

Comment: Можно отправить один JSON, в котором будет именно булево значение.